# Live Scrolling Twitter Feed

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter

Looking to add a live, scrolling twitter feed (of my own tweets only) to my .NET MVC 3 website. I've seen several jQuery plugins for this but is there a "defacto standard" or an alternative non-plugin way of doing this? I have no experience connecting to Twitter so any information you can provide would be helpful.

Basically, I just want a div (fixed width/height) to rotate through my most recent X number of tweets and once it reaches the end, just start over again at the beginning.

Comment: "defacto standard" is to use their API.

Comment: Kind of a pointless comment...obviously the Twitter API is required. I'm pretty sure the intent of the question is relatively clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twitter widgets](http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile) provided what I was looking for out of the box.